# What is the best practice to consume a pointer returned as an argument

Tags: c++, std

Normally when a pointer to an object is created and returned from a function you consume it using unique_ptr to ensure it is deleted at the end of the scope.

```
CustomType* GetTheObject(); // Let's say this the function signature and it returns a new object

void Main() {
   auto object = make_unique(GetTheObject());
   object->DoSomething();
   // Then the object is deleted automatically
}
```

What if the function signature is like this

```
bool GetTheObject(CustomType** object);
```

I can imagine a rather verbose way to consume it

```
void Main() {
   // Declare a pointer which we never need
   CustomType* object_ptr;
   if(GetTheObject(&object_ptr)) {
      // Then create a unique_ptr out of it
      auto object = make_unique(object_ptr);
      object->DoSomething();
      // Then the object is deleted automatically
   }
}
```

Is there a better recommended way how to consume an object in this case. I can think about another let's say unique_ptr2 class which implements & operator and then use it like

```
unique_ptr2 object;
if(GetTheObject(&object)) {
   // use it
}
```

Is there a ready to be used implementation of unique_ptr2 which would allow doing that? It still feel to be not ideal. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd assume (in modern code) that any raw pointer is a "observing" pointer and doesn't participate in ownership. So it shouldn't be necessary to "consume" it. If it's an owning pointer it should *already* be a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: In c++, the main function is spelled `main` and it must always have the return type `int`.

Comment: Of course, I'm talking about using a function which was created that way (bool GetTheObject(CustomType** object)), an API function let's say, where I have no control over it and I need to consume the result of that function in a best possible way. Regarding the "main" function, please, it was just an example to depict the actual question, you can call it "global" or whatever.

Comment: @Alex That's the problem with raw pointers. You can't assume if it's owning based on the type alone. If you trust the code base, you can rely on conventions. Otherwise, you need to look up the function's documentation or source dive to see what it is. If you *know* its an owning pointer, then the best thing may be to immediatly give that ownership to a `unique_ptr` like you do here. But since it looks like you can modify `GetTheObject`, I would bundle it with the return value.

Comment: Is your wording in respect of _"consume"_ accidential or intentional? Because if it's intentional, then there is only one correct solution, and that's exactly how you do it (seeing how you explained that you do not control `GetTheObject`). Consume means ownership (and responsibilty) is transferred, so `unique_ptr` is the right thing. `shared_ptr` would be _"I don't quite know who owns it"_, and a raw pointer is commonly interpreted similar to, or the same as `std::experimental::observer_ptr`, i.e. non-owning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be tempted to write code that automates the conversion to/from the unique ptr.  We generate a new function from our existing function "automatically" that has the same signature, but `T*` return values are `unique_ptr<T>` and `T**` arguments are `unique_ptr<T>*` arguments.

Then we inject the conversion boilerplate using RAII and template metaprogramming.

A `ptr_filler` is a RAII type that converts a `unique_ptr<T>*` into a `T**`:

```
template<class T>
struct ptr_filler {
  std::unique_ptr<T>* output = nullptr;
  T* temporary = nullptr;
  ptr_filler( std::unique_ptr<T>* bind ):output(bind) {}
  operator T**()&&{return &temporary;}
  ~ptr_filler() {
    if (temporary)
      *output = std::unique_ptr<T>(temporary);
  }
};
```

`ret_converter_t` does a type conversion from the C-style API to a C++ unique-ptr API:

```
template<class T> struct ret_converter { using type=T; };
template<class T> using ret_converter_t = typename ret_converter<T>::type;
template<class T> struct ret_converter<T*> { using type=std::unique_ptr<T>; };
```

`get_converter_t` converts argument types from the C-style API, to one that fills unique ptrs via a `ptr_filler`:

```
template<class T> struct get_converter { using type=T; };
template<class T> using get_converter_t = typename get_converter<T>::type;
template<class T> struct get_converter<T**> { using type=ptr_filler<T>; };
```

Finally, `call` deduces its arguments from the function pointer you pass it, then converts the arguments and retval to use unique ptr memory management, and calls the function `f` for you:

```
template<class R, class...Args>
ret_converter_t<R> call( R(* f)(Args...), get_converter_t<Args>... args ) {
  return static_cast<ret_converter_t<R>>( f( std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... ) );
}
```

now we can:

```
struct CustomType {
  int x;
};
CustomType* GetTheObject(int x) { return new CustomType{x}; }
bool MakeTheObject( CustomType** pp, int a, int b ) { *pp = new CustomType{a+b}; return a>b; }
```

we can do:

```
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<CustomType> ptr;
  std::cout << call( MakeTheObject, &ptr, 2, 1 ) << " = 1\n";
  std::cout << ptr->x << " = 3\n";
  ptr = call( GetTheObject, 7 );
  std::cout << ptr->x << " = 7\n";
}
```

You can get fancier with `call<MakeTheObject>` syntax, but it takes work.  This assumes that the API you are wrapping is an C-ish API but returns `new`'d objects.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97cbf11919f02539).

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. I'll probably try to refactor it to call it like call<MakeTheObject> but overall it looks almost what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that returning a `std::unique_ptr` would be safer than returning a raw pointer, since returning a raw pointer risks the calling code accidentally leaking the object.  I'd recommend doing it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class CustomType
{
   // ...
};

std::unique_ptr<CustomType> GetTheObject()
{
   if ((rand()%2) != 0) return std::make_unique<CustomType>();

   return std::unique_ptr<CustomType>();  // nothing to return, sorry
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   if (std::unique_ptr<CustomType> p = GetTheObject())
   {
      std::cout << "Got the object!" << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If you have to live with an existing function that you don't like the shape of and can't change, you can hide the ugliness inside a wrapper function and then call the wrapper function instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomType> PrettyGetTheObject()
{
   CustomObject * obj;
   if (GetTheObject(&obj)) return std::unique_ptr<CustomObject>(obj);

   return std::unique_ptr<CustomType>();  // nothing to return, sorry
}
```

Comment: I totally understand that. You are changing the initial conditions of the question. I have no control over the GetTheObject function signature. That is the problem. I want to find a best way to consume that pointer in those particular conditions.

Comment: @Alex There is no general "best way". When dealing with legacy code and potentially owning raw pointers, you just have to read the code to see what's going on and adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use a wrapper function. Example:

```
bool GetOriginal(char **pptr);

bool GetWrapped(std::unique_ptr<char> * puptr) {
  bool result;
  if (puptr != nullptr) {
    char * cptr;
    result = GetOriginal(&cptr);
    *puptr = std::make_unique(cptr);
  } else {
    result = GetOriginal(nullptr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This assumes the commonly used pattern of passing null to avoid getting a pointer to manage (e.g. if you're only interested in the return value).

If passing null to the original function is not part of its api, then you could of course use a reference to a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

If you have many such functions you could also write a general wrapper function for that, of course:

```cpp
template<typename Fn, typename T>
bool wrap(Fn fn, std::unique_ptr<T> * puptr) {
  bool result;
  if (puptr != nullptr) {
    T * cptr = nullptr;
    result = fn(&cptr);
    *puptr = std::make_unique(cptr);
  } else {
    result = fn(nullptr);
  }
  return result;
}

// usage: wrap(GetOriginal, &some_unique_ptr)
```

If the original function takes more arguments, then use `std::bind` or a lambda.

Comment: You think the best way is to create a wrapper for each function that returns a pointer as an argument? In this case I could technically create a method signature like std::unique_ptr<CustomType> GetTheObjectWrap() suggested in another answer but what if there are 10 or 30 functions, wrapping each of them seems like too much. I was thinking about creating a single adapter or another implementation of unique_ptr or something that I could do once and use it everywhere. Something that is not verbose and easy to use.

Comment: That's what I meant with the general wrapper .. e.g. for a usage similar to `wrap(GetOriginal, &the_unique_ptr)` in the end